# Select rows that were not selected in a previous query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC
```

Will output the full table:

```
id name weight
-- ---- ------
1  XXL 450
2  L   20
3  XL  30
4  XXL 875
5  S   2
```

Ordering by the weight and limiting to 3:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 3
```

Will output:

```
id name weight
-- ---- ------
4  XXL 875
1  XXL 450
3  XL  30
```

I want to select all the rows that were not selected in the last query, as such:

```
id name weight
-- ---- ------
2  L   20
5  S   2
```

Comment: Are you just looking for `ORDER BY weight ASC LIMIT 2`, or are you specifically trying to grab all rows **except** for the three heaviest rows?

Comment: No, it was just an example. I am specifically trying to exclude the last retrieved data. EDIT: Yes, grab all rows except for the three heaviest rows could be an option, but I still want to know how to exclude the retrieved data.

Comment: you want use this queries for pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.* FROM (    
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 3
) AS T ORDER BY T.id
```

The inner query order the rows by weight and crop the results starting from the 4th row to the 13th. The outer query order the partial result by id.

Comment: I want it to be ordered by the id and  I want it to exclude the first 3 heaviest rows (rows 4,1,3).

Comment: So, basically, you need to order by id the result of this: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY weight DESC OFFSET 3` (which excludes the 3 heaviest)

Comment: Try: `SELECT T.* FROM ( SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY weight DESC OFFSET 3 ) AS T ORDER BY T.id`

Comment: It does not work for me. Does the T stand for anything?

Comment: T is the alias given to the results of the inner query. Which error do you get?

Comment: error 1064. Seems like Mysql won't recognize OFFSET

Comment: try this, please: `SELECT T.* FROM ( SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 3 ) AS T ORDER BY T.id`

Answer (score 1):

I would just do:

```
select t.*
from t
where id not in (select id from t order by weight desc limit 3);
```

or:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     (select id from t order by weight desc limit 3) tt
     on t.id = tt.id
where tt.id is null;
```

However, you need to be very careful about what happens when two rows have the same weight.  So, I would recommend these two queries:

```
select id
from t
order by weight desc, id
limit 3

select t.*
from t left join
     (select id from t order by weight desc, id limit 3) tt
     on t.id = tt.id
where tt.id is null;
```